# Get location of browser using ipAPI and Django

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am using ipdata.io API to get the location of users visiting my website. I am able to implement the python code from the docs, however this returns the location of where my server is hosted. I am assuming this is because the views.py is being run on that server, which is in fact making the request, not the users browser. 
Without using javascript on the browser side, is it possible to get the location of the user using python requests on the server side?

This code "works" but it only returns the location of my server, not the users browser.

`views.py`

```
class infoRequestPage(CreateView):
    model = InfoRequest
    form_class = moreInfoForm
    template_name = 'info_request.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        payload = {"api-key": "myapikey"}
        response = requests.get('https://api.ipdata.co', params=payload).json()
        info_City = response['city']
        info_Region = response['region']
        info_Country = response['country_name']
        pageVisit = InfoRequest(
            infoCity = info_City,
            infoRegion = info_Region,
            infoCountry = info_Country,
            pageVisited = "infoRequest",)
        pageVisit.save()
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get a precise/GPS location from the client without Javascript.

Your code does not actually run on the client's machine; only on your own server. A [browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) would get the location of the client (if permission is granted) which can thereafter be sent to the server to be processed.

What you seem to be trying to do is calling an API that will examine an IP address which can be used to identify the rough area somebody is in. But the host performing the request is the server, as you are doing it in a Python code.

I don't suggest using this API on the client, as you would need to expose your APIkey to do so.